# Jquery text() doesn't work outside chrome console

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have this small piece of code

HTML

```
<div class="select">
   <p></p>
</div>

<div class="option">
   <p class="active">text</p>
</div>
```

JS

```
$('.option p').click(function() {    
   if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
       $(this).removeClass('active');
       if ($('.option p.active').length == 0) {
           $('.select p').text('some text');
       }
   }
})
```

If I run this code in the chrome console, it works perfectly. But if I run it in my programme, it doesn't work (the `.select p` text is not changed). I tried putting an `alert()` after `text()` to see if it would execute, and apparently `alert()` is executed, so `text()` should also be executed. I don't understand why it is not being executed in my programme (it was working perfectly a few weeks ago)

Comment: What are `$(p)` and `$(this)` when you run the code? Pleast post a [mre].

Comment: And what are `text1` and `text2`?

Comment: @Barmar I've update the question. Thanks

Comment: What element are you trying to remove the class from? The code isn't inside an event handler, so what is `this` expected to be?

Comment: The default value of `this` is `window`, so `$(this).removeClass('active')` will remove the class from the window, not the `<p>` element.

Comment: Are you assuming that inside the `if`, it will automatically set `this` to the same element you tested? That's not how `this` works.

Comment: @Barmar I forgot to change "this" to ".option p" in the question. The code is embedded in a much longer code, it would be complicated to write it all here and I have tried to simplify it as best I could, but I forgot to change "this", sorry. I?ve update the question

Comment: That will remove the class from all `.option p` elements. So the next `if` is guaranteed to succeed.

Comment: It seems to work for me: https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/3gfp6uxb/1/

Comment: Your first `if` tests whether *any* of the `.option p` elements has the class. If any of them do, it removes the class from all of them (assuming you change `$(this)` to `$('.option p')`).

Comment: We don't need all the code, but you need to post a [mre] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @Barmar In fact, the "if" works correctly if I run the entire block of code in the chrome console, but it does not work if I run my programme. A few weeks ago (the last time I tested it) it worked correctly. Today it no longer works, but the code is the same. I can't really understand what the problem is

Comment: @AlessioScalzo Are you having the same issue in the jsfiddle he linked? If not, then please modify it to produce the minimal reproducible example you can create. My guess is that your script is being loaded before the HTML elements, so your selectors aren't able to find the elements yet. You can fix this by either moving your script tag to the bottom of the page, or listening for the document ready event.

Comment: @robere2 exactly what I thought too. I have already tried but it still doesn't seem to work

Comment: Can you explain what it's supposed to do? In the question you only have one `.option p` and one `.select p`, but I assume the real application has multiple of them. How is it supposed to work in that case?

Comment: Are they created dynamically? If so, how is the code supposed to work with that?

Comment: @Barmar in the HTML is created one div with class "select" and 5 divs with class "option". The paragraph inside the "option" div contains the names of 5 vehicles (car, motorbike etc.). When clicking on the paragraph of the div with "option" class, the content of the paragraph clicked on is written in the paragraph of the div with "select" class and the "active" class is added to the clicked paragraph. If the user clicks again on the paragraph with class "active", the class is removed and a default sentence (no vehicle selected) should appear in the paragraph of the div with class "select".

Comment: This is what you should do. No div is dynamically created

Comment: Where is the click handler in the code you posted?

Comment: @Barmar I have not included it as I do not think it is necessary to solve the problem. However, I have updated the question code correctly

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the code inside a click handler. When you click on an element, do different things depending on whether you clicked on the active or inactive element.

If it's active, remove the class and put the default text in the select paragraph.

If it's not active, remove the class from all the other elements and add the class to this element, and display its text in the select paragraph.

```js
$(".option p").click(function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass("active")) {
    $(this).removeClass("active");
    $(".select p").text("No option selected");
  } else {
    $(".option p").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
    $(".select p").text($(this).text());
  }
});
```

```css
.option p.active {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="select">
  <p>text 1</p>
</div>

<div class="option">
  <p class="active">text 1</p>
</div>
<div class="option">
  <p>text 2</p>
</div>
<div class="option">
  <p>text 3</p>
</div>
```